# Write dictionary in Bundle's json file, Swift 4, iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization

I have a local .json file and I want to read and write data to it. With reading, I have no problems:

```
let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "categories", withExtension: "json")
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: file)
let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
```

But writing doesn't work. My code(`jsonData` & `file` not nil):

```
let dict = ["data": categories.compactMap { $0.dictionary }]
let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "categories", withExtension: "json")
let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: [])
try? jsonData?.write(to: file!)
```

.json file inside looks like this:

```
{
    "data" : [
        {
            "id" : "new",
            "name" : "New"
        }]
}
```

Comment: Replace `try?` with `try` in a `do - catch` block and `print` the `error`

Comment: @vadian Code executes without errors

Comment: I thought you get an error that the application bundle is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit an embedded file. You have to first copy it from Bundle to `Documents` directory and then work ( edit ) on this file